GCP Memstore Discovery End Point connectivity
We are using spring session which uses Lettuce connection factory to connect to the GCP redis single instance.
We are planning to move to GCP redis cluster which has Discovery End point (single IP backed by multiple redis nodes)
How to integrate lettuce connectivity with spring session.
Is there any specific spring boot version which supports GCP memstore Discovery End Point connectivity..
Tried to upgrade lettuce version as suggested by GCP Documents
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/cluster/client-library-code-samples
But seeing few issues.
